# Hiding Unused cells with a button

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and have been attempting to do this with little research. I am trying to hide all the unused rows on a sheet with a click of a button. I keep getting error codes with anything I try so any tips would be fantastic!

```
Sub HideCellsPrac()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim FinalRow As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

FinalRow = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Set rng = ws.Range(FinalRow & "A94")

rng.Group
rng.Hidden = True


End Sub
```

More detail: I am trying to use FinalRow to find the last data input in column A (in my case the final row would be 51), then create a range down to cell A94 and group that range then hide it.

Comment: `Set rng = ws.Range("A" & FinalRow & ":A94")` and use. `rng.entirerow.hidden = true`

Comment: @ScottCraner I am running into issues with it hiding the entire A column down to A94. I am not sure if the FinalRow is working or if it could be something else.

Comment: put `msgbox rng.address` somewhere after setting the variable and see what you get.

Comment: @ScottCraner I got $A$4:$A$839, I increased the range to 839, could that have been the issue?

Comment: no, it means that A5 is blank.

Comment: may be better if you do: `FinalRow = ws.Range("A840").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @ScottCraner That was it! Thank you so much for your assistance. Any tips on how to get better at VBA and Excel?

Comment: Just keep practicing. If you get stuck, ask.  That's it.

Comment: @ScottCraner: Add your comment as an answer instead of answering in the comments.